# Manga where the main character has a cursed kitchen knife

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a fantasy manga set in Japan during the Edo period. The main character is a chef(?) And his father passed down a possessed kitchen knife. His childhood friend is cursed, and if I recall correctly he has to kill and feed her a giant flying goldfish. I believe chapter 1 has him killing a giant octopus. There's also an office where they have to kill and cook these giant sea animals for jobs.

I don't remember too much since I read it probably in 2020 or some time around then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is The Kajiki Chef: Divine Cuisine, by Sanami Suzuki.

The giant sea creatures are called kajiki, and are considered to be created by the gods as food for gods.

from [the TvTropes page:](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/TheKajikiChefDivineCuisine)

> Young chef Toya Yasoya lives out an ordinary life as adopted son of the Yasoya family and restaurant in a small town with his childhood friend, Izayoi Kukui, the young heiress of the noble Kukui household. When one day a kajiki salmon shark bites off Izayoi's arm, Toya awakens and forms a bond with the steel knife tsukomogami Hihiirokane in order to kill the shark and feed its divine flesh to Izayoi to heal her. Toya now sets out to hunt down as many kajiki as possible in the hopes that one of them will have the ability to restore Izayoi's missing arm.